# Using Cake, start a process in a new window

Tags: .net, .net-core, cakebuild

I am trying to use Cake to build my application and start it. I can get it to start one process, but I want to start multiple processes in separate windows. For example, I would like to start my API server and web server in separate powershell windows.

Here is an example of what I have tried

```
Task("run-api")
.Does(() => 
{
    var path = root + File("api\\src\api.fsproj");
    DotNetCoreRun(path);
});
```

OR

```
Task("run-api")
.Does(() => 
{
    var settings = new PowershellSettings 
    {
        WorkingDirectory = root + Directory("api\\src\\")
    };

    StartPowershellScript("dotnet run api.fsproj", settings);
});
```

Both of these just start the process in the current window.  I don't see anything in the documentation to specify a new window.

- https://cakebuild.net/dsl/dotnetcore/
- https://cakebuild.net/dsl/process/
- https://github.com/SharpeRAD/Cake.Powershell#referencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, but its just normal .NET base class libraries. Is there any Cake addin that does this?

```
Task("run-api")
.Does(() => 
{
    var info = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "dotnet",
        Arguments = "run api.fsproj",
        WorkingDirectory = (root + File("api\\src\\")).ToString()
    };

    Process.Start(info);
});
```